# GCC error for ""vmull.u16 q7, d19, d8[0]" but not for ""vmull.u16 q7, d19, d7[0]"

Tags: assembly, gcc, vectorization, simd, neon

I am using Arm GNU Toolchain 12.2.Rel1 (Build arm-12.24)) 12.2.1 20221205 on Windows 11, and on compilation of a sequence of NEON instructions (vector multiplication by scalar):

`vmull.u16 q7, d19, d0[0] vmull.u16 q7, d19, d8[0]`

the first one compiles correctly but for the second one I get an error message:

ccuFDHko.s:5546: Error: scalar out of range for multiply instruction -- `vmull.u16 q7,d19,d8[0]'

After testing a couple more of combinations of different registers for the three parameters, I am inclined to conclude that only registers lower than d8 can be used for the scalar (third parameter).

I did not find any reference on this restriction on NEON Programmer's Guide nor on ARM site.

Also, when I used the intrinsic:
uint32x4_t vmull_lane_u16(uint16x4_t vec1, uint16x4_t val2, __constrange(0, 3) int val3);

it always compiled with "d7[0]" as the scalar.

I appreciate getting any hints on this behavior or a reasonable explanation.

Thanks,
Julio

Comment: https://developer.arm.com/documentation/den0024/a/AArch64-Floating-point-and-NEON/NEON-and-Floating-Point-architecture/Scalar-data-and-NEON - "*NEON scalars can be 8-bit, 16-bit, 32-bit, or 64-bit values. **Other than multiply instructions**, instructions that access scalars can access any element in the register file."*  But I don't know where in the ARM manuals a special restriction would be documented.  https://developer.arm.com/documentation/dui0473/m/neon-instructions/vmull doesn't mention one (or scalar source operands at all)

Comment: Hi, Peter, thanks for the info. Your first reference is for the ARMv8-A architecture, whereas I am using a Cortex-A9 which is ARMv7-A (sorry for not mentioning it on my post). And on your second reference you nailed it! Under the same "NEON scalars" entry in the ARM Compiler armasm User Guide Version 5.06 link (https://developer.arm.com/documentation/dui0473/m/neon-programming/neon-scalars), it is well documented: "16-bit scalars are restricted to registers D0-D7, with x in the range 0-3". Thanks a lot!

Comment: I knew the first link I found was for AArch64, but it did mention NEON (which means 32-bit ARM).  But yeah, now that I think about it, probably they just mentioned that to point out that the ARM32 limitation didn't apply for AArch64's ASIMD version of the same instruction, so it made sense that part of the manual didn't go into details about the AArch32 state of ARMv8.

Comment: I can assure you that your assumption is right: You can use up to `d7` register for 16bit scalars. (up to `d15` for 32bit ones) I don't remember exactly where I read it, but I suppose it was in the assembler guide in the  `Cortex-A8` era. If I'm not mistaken, it's the only neon register restriction on `ArmV7`